# loop through selection to calculate a value for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have stored procedure that takes 4 parameters: startdate, enddate, allocationID & language. The ones that really matter for my question are the dates.

With these parameters the stored procedure will gather car date form different tables and return a selection containing empty records for each month and filled records for each car per month WHERE the car has a valid mileage value. So if the dates would be '2008-01-01' and '2008-06-01' this is an example result.

[image]

In the example the first car has values for all the months, but the second one is missing the first month. What I need to do now is add logic so that every car in the selection has a row for each month. Then I must calculate the mileage value for that month by taking the previous and the next mileage values.

I have an Idea how I would do this in C# for example but I am not that experienced with SQL. My question is how can I iterate through the months and then iterate again through the carID's and check if they have a mileage value or not.

I know I'll have to make a temp table but I have no clue how to do this with only a while and case.

### EDIT: Here is the query that I use to test, has the same code as the procedure

```
--DECLARATION VARS
    DECLARE @Taal varchar(5) = 'en-us'
    DECLARE @VanDate datetime = '2008-01-01'
    DECLARE @TotDate datetime = '2008-06-01'
    DECLARE @AllocationID AS uniqueidentifier = 'BD83AEDE-6DFB-4DF5-9F18-C373D6A468D1'

    DECLARE @TaalID int 
    DECLARE @Months int
    DECLARE @FirstDay AS DateTime
    DECLARE @LastDay AS Datetime

    DECLARE @DefaultFirstDay as Datetime
    DECLARE @DefaultLastDay as Datetime

    DECLARE @ControlDay AS datetime

    --DEFAULT MONTHS SPAN
    SET @Months = 18   

    SELECT @TaalID = MIN(eMK_Languages.ID) 
    FROM eMK_Languages WHERE LEFT(eMK_Languages.LangCode,2) = LEFT (@Taal,2)

    Set @Lastday = ISNULL(@TotDate,dateadd(dd,0,datediff(dd,0,{fn NOW()})));
    --select @Lastday as Lastday;
    Set @Firstday = ISNULL(@VanDate, 
    DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm, -(1-@Months) , @LastDay))-1),DATEADD(mm, 1 -(@Months) , @LastDay)));
    --select @Firstday as Firstday;
    SET @ControlDay = dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0,@LastDay));

;WITH 

MonthList (MonthDate) AS -- lijst van maanden
(   
SELECT 
    DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm, 0 , @LastDay))-1),DATEADD(mm, 0 , @LastDay))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(mm, -1, MonthDate) 
        FROM MonthList
    WHERE (MonthDate > @FirstDay)
),

AllocationList AS 
(
    SELECT  COST.CostAllocationID, 
            COST.Name as AllocationName
    FROM    eMK_CostAllocation AS COST
    WHERE (COST.CostAllocationID = @AllocationID OR @AllocationID IS NULL)
            AND (COST.StartDate <= @LastDay OR COST.StartDate IS NULL) 
            AND (COST.EndDate IS NULL OR COST.EndDate >= @FirstDay)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,NULL
)  
,
AllocationCrossList AS 
(
    SELECT  ML.MonthDate,
            DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,ML.MonthDate)) as endmonth,
            ML.MonthDate as  X_AXIS,
            DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,ML.MonthDate)) X_AXIS_2,
            AL.CostAllocationID,
            AL.AllocationName
    FROM MonthList AS ML
    CROSS JOIN AllocationList AS AL
)  
,CarList AS 
(   
    SELECT 
    M.MonthDate as beginmonth
,   DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,M.MonthDate)) as endmonth
,   M.MonthDate as  X_AXIS
,   DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,M.MonthDate)) X_AXIS_2
,   C.CarID 
--, (dbo.fGetAllocationNameFromDate(C.CarID,DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,M.MonthDate)))) as AllocationName
,   dbo.fGetAllocationFromDate(C.CarID,DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,M.MonthDate))) as AllocationID
,   C.StartDate
,   C.FinalEndDate
,   dbo.fGetTranslation(C.CarTypeID,@TaalID) as Nature
,   C.BuiltYear
,   VHC.Co2Emission

FROM
    eMK_Car C
    CROSS JOIN MonthList M 
    CROSS JOIN eMK_Vehicle VHC

 WHERE 
    (
    C.StartDate <= DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,M.MonthDate))
    AND (C.FinalEndDate IS NULL OR C.FinalEndDate >= M.MonthDate )
    AND C.VehicleID = VHC.VehicleID
    ) 
)       


, unionlist as (SELECT 
    'Fuelcard' as oorsprong
,   CAR.beginmonth
,   CAR.endmonth
,   CAR.X_AXIS
,   CAR.CarID 
,   CAR.AllocationID
,   (CASE   WHEN CAR.CarID IS NULL 
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END ) as ValidData
,   CAR.Co2Emission
,   fuelcardrefill.Kilometer as kilometerstand
,   fuelcardrefill.FK_FuelType
,   fuelcardrefill.Date as datum

From    CarList AS CAR inner join
        dbo.eMK_CarFuelCard as carfuelcard On CAR.CarID = carfuelcard.CarID inner join
        dbo.eMK_FuelCard as fuelcard on carfuelcard.FuelCardID = fuelcard.ID inner join 
        dbo.eMK_FuelCard_Refill as fuelcardrefill on fuelcard.ID = fuelcardrefill.FK_FuelCard

Where 
      (fuelcardrefill.Date >= CAR.beginmonth and fuelcardrefill.Date <= CAR.endmonth)

UNION

SELECT 
    'Costs' as oorsprong
,   CAR.beginmonth
,   CAR.endmonth
,   CAR.X_AXIS
,   CAR.CarID 
,   CAR.AllocationID
,   (CASE   WHEN CAR.CarID IS NULL 
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END ) as ValidData
,   CAR.Co2Emission
,   COSTS.Mileage as kilometerstand
,   NULL
,   COSTS.DateInvoice as datum

FROM
    CarList AS CAR inner join
    dbo.Emk_Cost as COSTS on CAR.CarID = COSTS.CarID 

Where 
      (COSTS.CostDate > beginmonth and COSTS.CostDate < endmonth)

UNION

SELECT 
    'Caruse_start' as oorsprong
,   CAR.beginmonth
,   CAR.endmonth
,   CAR.X_AXIS
,   CAR.CarID 
,   CAR.AllocationID
,   (CASE   WHEN CAR.CarID IS NULL 
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END ) as ValidData
,   CAR.Co2Emission
,   CARUSE.MileageStart as kilometerstand
,   NULL
,   CARUSE.StartDate as datum

FROM
    CarList AS CAR inner join
    dbo.eMK_CarUse as CARUSE on CARUSE.CarID = CAR.CarID

Where 
      (CARUSE.StartDate >= beginmonth and CARUSE.StartDate <= endmonth)


UNION

SELECT 
    'Caruse_end' as oorsprong
,   CAR.beginmonth
,   CAR.endmonth
,   CAR.X_AXIS
,   CAR.CarID 
,   CAR.AllocationID
,   (CASE   WHEN CAR.CarID IS NULL 
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END ) as ValidData
,   CAR.Co2Emission
,   CARUSE.MileageEnd as kilometerstand
,   NULL
,   CARUSE.EndDate as datum

FROM
    CarList AS CAR inner join
    dbo.eMK_CarUse as CARUSE on CARUSE.CarID = CAR.CarID

Where 
      (CARUSE.EndDate >= beginmonth and CARUSE.EndDate <= endmonth)


UNION

SELECT 
    'AllocationCross' as oorsprong
,   AL.MonthDate as beginmonth
,   AL.endmonth
,   AL.X_AXIS
,   NULL as CarID 
,   AL.CostAllocationID
,   'N' as ValidData
,   NULL
,   NULL
,   NULL
,   NULL

From    AllocationCrossList as AL)

, resultunionlist as (
SELECT 
        UL1.*,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT * 
            FROM unionlist AS UL2
            WHERE
                UL2.CarID = UL1.CarID AND
                UL2.datum < UL1.datum AND
                UL2.kilometerstand < UL1.kilometerstand OR
                UL1.oorsprong = 'Caruse_start'
        )
        THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
        END AS validkmstand
FROM unionlist as UL1)

, totalmileagelist as (
SELECT
    'Fuelcard' as oorsprong
,   CAR.CarID 
,   (CASE   WHEN CAR.CarID IS NULL 
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END ) as ValidData
,   CAR.Co2Emission
,   fuelcardrefill.Kilometer as kilometerstand
,   fuelcardrefill.FK_FuelType
,   fuelcardrefill.Date as datum

From    CarList AS CAR inner join

        dbo.eMK_CarFuelCard as carfuelcard On CAR.CarID = carfuelcard.CarID inner join
        dbo.eMK_FuelCard as fuelcard on carfuelcard.FuelCardID = fuelcard.ID inner join 
        dbo.eMK_FuelCard_Refill as fuelcardrefill on fuelcard.ID = fuelcardrefill.FK_FuelCard

Where 
      (fuelcardrefill.Date < @VanDate )

      UNION

SELECT 
    'Caruse_start' as oorsprong
,   CAR.CarID 
,   (CASE   WHEN CAR.CarID IS NULL 
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END ) as ValidData
,   CAR.Co2Emission
,   CARUSE.MileageStart as kilometerstand
,   NULL
,   CARUSE.StartDate as datum

FROM
    CarList AS CAR inner join
    dbo.eMK_CarUse as CARUSE on CARUSE.CarID = CAR.CarID

Where 
      (CARUSE.StartDate < @VanDate)
)

,   resultlist as (
SELECT
    CarID
,   '01/01/2000' as beginmonth
,   NULL as X_AXIS
,   MAX(kilometerstand) as Kilometers
,   MAX(Co2Emission) as CO2

FROM
    totalmileagelist
GROUP BY CarID

UNION

SELECT
    CarID
,   beginmonth
,   X_AXIS
,   MAX(kilometerstand) as Kilometers
,   MAX(Co2Emission) as CO2

FROM
resultunionlist
GROUP BY CarID, beginmonth, X_AXIS
)

,   withoutprevalueslist as (
select ml.*,
       (ml.Kilometers - mlprev.Kilometers) as diff
from resultlist ml outer apply
     (select top 1 ml2.*
      from resultlist ml2
      where ml2.CarId = ml.CarId and
            ml2.beginmonth < ml.beginmonth
      order by ml2.beginmonth desc
     ) mlprev
)


SELECT *
FROM withoutprevalueslist
WHERE beginmonth >= @VanDate

option (MAXRECURSION 999)
```

Comment: Please share your stored procedure

Comment: Pasted it in, it is the query I use to test. But it has the same code.

Comment: That procedure seems very excessive. I'd advice you to split the problem into multiple smaller problems and solve each one. First make a query which ensure data integrity so to speak (that each car has each month). Secondly do a query which calculate the diff which is basically just a one-line subselect depending on edge logic.

Comment: Yes but if I want to check if each car has a row for each month, I still need some sort of nested loop right ?

Comment: No you need to outer join to a 'month' table. This will give you a record for each month, and optionally, any car records that match that month. If you find a month where the car record is NULL you know it's missing.